# Migrating data from nopCommerce to Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, sql, nopcommerce, umbraco7

In the process of building a new Umbraco site for a customer, I am facing the task of migrating all the content such as products, categories, product pictures, etc from nopCommerce to Umbraco 7. In order to keep all the relationships and mappings between the products and the categories, the products and its pictures, and do not lose any important information, I just use the same IDs that appear in the nopCommerce tables when importing the data from the tables to Umbraco.

However, this approach is provoking some issues once I have completed the import. As an example let's say we already have the product that has been imported into Umbraco:

```
Name: Product A
ImageId: 1002
```

Now, we are going to edit it and add another picture. Given a picture that is stored in the Media section in Umbraco, and therefore it has an ID which *casually* is 1002, if I try to assign it to the imported Product A which already has a picture assigned with ID = 1002, there is a duplication of the Primary Key ID.

What is the best way to avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% percent sure how is your import running but I would suggest to import the images from products first into the Media section and get the id of the insertion in the DB, and use that ID (that shouldn't be duplicated) to link it to the product. In this way you avoid any possible duplication.

Regards